# SharePoint Online "Page Elements" style for Format Text missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, formatting

We are currently experiencing a really weird bug where the "Page Elements" is missing under the Font Styles under Format Text.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The weird thing is, it was working fine ever since we deployed it (5 months ago) and it just happened now.

All SharePoint portals inside our O365 (let's call it O365 One) is affected.

Strangely, we have a different O365 (let's call it O365 Two) account, and the "Page Elements" style is working there.

I even tried adding Custom Styles as defined here: https://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-add-custom-styles-to-the-ribbon-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

But it also did not work for (O365 One). However, Custom Styles worked for (O365 Two).

Can anyone help / know what to do?

Thank you!

EDIT:

We found something strange; the javascripts on the problematic sites are being directed to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.5131.1203/sp.js"></script>
```

While the correct sites are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/15815/_layouts/15/16.0.5117.1213/sp.init.js"></script>
```

But the things is, we haven't done anything to change it. Might it be Microsoft's side?

EDIT 2:

Using responseheaders, found out that the SP Version of the Problematic Sites is : 16.0.0.5131

While the correct sites are: 16.0.0.5117

It seems that 16.0.0.5131 is problematic?

Comment: This seems to be an MS problem, please open a support ticket directly with them to get the proper attention

Comment: We're having the exact same problem. Have not found a solution for the problem yet. /Thomas

Comment: Thanks, we first noticed it around Monday. How about yours? Since we experience the same thing, I think its MS problem? If you manage to fix it, can you let me know how you did it?

Comment: Seems we can also reproduce this in one of our tenants. Bugreport to MS is the way forward I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Do your affected sites have custom css? Is first release enabled for the tenant? Looks like related to https://community.office365.com/en-us/b/news_hub/archive/2016/02/24/updated-feature-sharepoint-online-theming-for-first-release-customers-only

Comment: Thanks adsls630, that's interesting. Yes we are using custom css / masterpage. I saw that it says it was changed Feb 26? The weird thing is, we just experienced it last Monday (Apr 3). Before it was okay. Also, our other tenants seem to be working fine.

Comment: Looks like Feb 26 is for First Release. You may check your office 365 message center. I saw on in my tenant said April 15 for non first release.

Comment: First Release tenants have already been notified of this change happening on March 24. All others, will happen on April 15.

Comment: Thanks adsl. We just checked our other tenants (2 tenants) and it seems they are also experiencing the same issue now. Confirmed that they are both now on version 5131 (the problematic version I mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft has fixed it. We can now use the Page Elements again on the styling.

Hope everything is okay with others.

Comment: Still does not work. They used to in 2019